# Google Script - Create a Folder "Year" with sub-folder "Month"

Tags: google-apps-script, directory

Hopefully someone can help me with this. I am wanting to create a script that will archive a sheet every 24 hours so far I have a script made that emails it.

I am wanting to make a script that if the folder does not exist, create a new folder by "Year" and a sub-folder by "month" inside and place a copy of the sheet inside time stamped with the date of the transfer. I am hoping to find a solution to make this an automated script.

```
function makeCopy() { 
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"); 
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate; 
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()) 
  file.makeCopy(name, destination); 
}
```

Cheers.

EDIT

I have made some progress on the script now to make the Folders and sub folders, but is there an easier way then this?

ok I have managed to get the subfolders created is there an easier way to do it?

```
    function makeFolder() { 
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var folderYearDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy");
    var folderMonthDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MMMM");
    var name = "Archive - " + formattedDate; // file name
    var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx").getFoldersByName("Archive")

    var yearExist = parent.next();
    var yearFolders = yearExist.getFoldersByName(folderYearDate);
    if(yearFolders.hasNext()){
        var yearFolder = yearFolders.next().getId();
        Logger.log('Yes, There is a year folder.')
        //return;
    } else {
        var yearFolder = yearExist.createFolder(folderYearDate).getId();

        Logger.log('There was no year folder. But created')
        //return;
    }
    var child = 

  DriveApp.getFolderById("1qZh_O3kbDfDEL2QJoU7U1tUudmjSgWVS").getFoldersByName(folderYearDate)
    var monthExist = child.next();
    var monthFolders = monthExist.getFoldersByName(folderMonthDate);
    if(monthFolders.hasNext()){
        var yearFolderExist = yearFolders.next().getName();
        Logger.log('Yes, There is a month folder.')
        return;
    } else {
        monthExist.createFolder(folderMonthDate);
        Logger.log('There was no month folder. But created')
        return;
    }
    }
```

NEW EDIT

I have compiled the new scripts and done what I could to make a copy of the Archive data too by a little work around again if anyone knows of a cleaner way to do it it be much appreciated.

```
function makeFolder() {
var ss              = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet           = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE");
var CurrentDate     = new Date();  
var oldDate         = new Date();
oldDate.setDate(CurrentDate.getDate()-1);
var formattedDate   = Utilities.formatDate(oldDate, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var folderYearDate  = Utilities.formatDate(oldDate, "GMT", "yyyy");
var folderMonthDate = Utilities.formatDate(oldDate, "GMT", "MMMM");
var name = "Archive - " + formattedDate; // file name
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx").getFoldersByName("Archive")
var yearExist = parent.next();
var yearFolders = yearExist.getFoldersByName(folderYearDate);
if(yearFolders.hasNext()){
    var yearFolder = yearFolders.next()
    Logger.log('Yes, There is a year folder.')
    //return;
} else {
    var yearFolder = yearExist.createFolder(folderYearDate)
    Logger.log('There was no year folder. But created')
    //return;
}
var monthFolders = yearFolder.getFoldersByName(folderMonthDate);
if(monthFolders.hasNext()){
    var monthFolder = monthFolders.next()
    Logger.log('Yes, There is a month folder.')
} else {
    var monthFolder = yearFolder.createFolder(folderMonthDate);
    Logger.log('There was no month folder. But created')
}
var folderId = monthFolder.getId();
var resource = {
  title: name,
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{ id: folderId }]
}
var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource)
var fileId = fileJson.id
Logger.log(fileId)
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
sheet.copyTo(destination);
var removeSheet = destination.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var reName      = destination.getSheetByName("Copy of ARCHIVE");
reName.setName("ARCHIVE");
destination.deleteSheet(removeSheet);
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: At the Moment I am using the following script<br/>`function makeCopy() {

var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())
file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}`

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to archive this every day? Or once per month? At a glance, you're not testing for the existence of a folder before archiving, so you'll need some logic to do that before you can create a new one.

Comment: I am already able to create a archive file every 24 hours to a folder of my choosing, but what I would like to be able to do is to send this file to a folder titled after the Month so if the file was created today 27/2/18 this file will be copied to a folder called February in a parent folder of 2018 and if the folder does not exist to create it.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say finding this code was super helpful for a project I was working on. I figured out a part of the issue you were having OP. I'm suspecting the error had to do with the types of variables you were using with makeCopy. The name HAS to be a **string**, and the destination has to be a **folder** object type.

Also, makeCopy has to use a file variable type. If you are trying to create a sheet, you'll need to copy the whole workbook and remove the excess sheets afterward with some extra code.

Here's my completed code so you can see how I was able to get it to work.

```
// Program makes new folder and copies file to that new folder.

function makeFolder() { 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Gets active spreadsheet script is installed to
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var folderYearDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy");
var folderMonthDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MMMM");
var name = "Comp SnapShot - " + formattedDate; // file name
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXX").getFoldersByName("Archive") // Sets parent folder and searches inside of it for "Archive" 

/*Script now searches through the year folders, to ensure we have the current year already created. 
  If the script finds that the current year isn't created, it will create a new year folder. */

var yearExist = parent.next();
var yearFolders = yearExist.getFoldersByName(folderYearDate);
if(yearFolders.hasNext()){
    var yearFolder = yearFolders.next()
    Logger.log('Yes, There is a year folder.')
    //return;
} else {
    var yearFolder = yearExist.createFolder(folderYearDate)

    Logger.log('There was no year folder. But created')
    //return;
}

/* Searches through the Month folders which are inside of the previously checked year folder. 
   It then looks to see if the current month exists, if it does it continues on. 
   If it doesn't, it will create a new month folder and set the active folder variable (monthFolder)
   to the new folder it just created.   */  

  
var monthFolders = yearFolder.getFoldersByName(folderMonthDate);
if(monthFolders.hasNext()){
    var monthFolder = monthFolders.next()
    Logger.log('Yes, There is a month folders.')

} else {
    var monthFolder = yearFolder.createFolder(folderMonthDate);
    Logger.log('There was no month folder. But created')
}
  
  // Selects file to copy
  // Copies file to monthFolder which was checked or created earlier
var nameString = name.toString();   // Ensures name is a string which is required for the makeCopy peramater to work.
var cableDahmerComp = DriveApp.getFileById("XXX"); // Change the string here to the file ID you want to copy
cableDahmerComp.makeCopy(nameString, monthFolder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is pretty spot on, just a few minor changes. Mostly to remove redundant code. 
1) Instead of obtaining the id of year folder you can get the folder object itself.

```
if(yearFolders.hasNext()){
        var yearFolder = yearFolders.next()
    } else {
        var yearFolder = yearExist.createFolder(folderYearDate)
    }
```

2) Directly utilize this folder object to look for a folder with the name of the month.

```
var monthFolders = yearFolder.getFoldersByName(folderMonthDate);
```

3) Now similar as before, you can create or get the folder object

```
if(monthFolders.hasNext()){
    var monthFolder = monthFolders.next()
    Logger.log('Yes, There is a month folder.')

} else {
    var monthFolder = yearFolder.createFolder(folderMonthDate);
    Logger.log('There was no month folder. But created')

}
  monthFolder.createFile(name, "SO help File")
  monthFolder.addFile(file)
```

Note: you can use either [`createFile`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename-content) to make a new file from scratch or if you already have the file created you can add it to the folder using the [`addFile`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addfilechild) function.

Your Final code:

```
function makeFolder() { 
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var folderYearDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy");
var folderMonthDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MMMM");
var name = "Archive - " + formattedDate; // file name
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx").getFoldersByName("Archive")
var yearExist = parent.next();
var yearFolders = yearExist.getFoldersByName(folderYearDate);
if(yearFolders.hasNext()){
    var yearFolder = yearFolders.next()
    Logger.log('Yes, There is a year folder.')
    //return;
} else {
    var yearFolder = yearExist.createFolder(folderYearDate)

    Logger.log('There was no year folder. But created')
    //return;
}

var monthFolders = yearFolder.getFoldersByName(folderMonthDate);
if(monthFolders.hasNext()){
    var monthFolder = monthFolders.next()
    Logger.log('Yes, There is a month folder.')

} else {
    var monthFolder = yearFolder.createFolder(folderMonthDate);
    Logger.log('There was no month folder. But created')

}
  monthFolder.createFile(name, "SO help File")
}
```

Comment: this works great, when it comes to the file though I have a main spreadsheet with a worksheet inside called Archive, this is the sheet I was to have copied and made into it's own file to to be sent to the I have been trying to get the following code to work but keeps coming up with errors at the moment 

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE");
 sheet.makeCopy(name, monthFolder);`